# PowerShell List of distribution groups and members? (Office 365)

Tags: powershell, exchange, office365

I'm looking for a way to export a list of distribution groups along with the members of each group via PowerShell on Office 365.

I've found scripts that export a list of users and the groups they belong too but not the other way round?

I got close with this:

```
$saveto = "C:\\listmembers.txt"

Get-DistributionGroup | sort name | ForEach-Object {

    "`r`n$($_.Name)`r`n=============" | Add-Content $saveto
    Get-DistributionGroupMember $_ | sort Name | ForEach-Object {
        If($_.RecipientType -eq "UserMailbox")
            {
                $_.Name + " (" + $_.PrimarySMTPAddress + ")" | Add-Content $saveto
            }
    }
}
```

But it produces a text file with a list of all Distribution groups and is divided nicely by the "====" but no members are displayed. I receive the below error on each group it finds:

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert value "GROUP NAME" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.DistributionGroupMemberIdParameter". Error:
 "Cannot convert hashtable to an object of the following type: Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.DistributionGroupMemberIdParameter. Hashtable-to-Object conversion is not supported in rest
ricted language mode or a Data section."
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-DistributionGroupMember], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Get-DistributionGroupMember
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the response from Vaibhav but it didn't work straight away. I resolved my issue with the following code.

```
$saveto = "listmembers.txt"
Get-DistributionGroup $_.Alias | sort Name | Foreach-Object {
"`r`n$($_.DisplayName)`r`n=============" | Add-Content $saveto
    Get-DistributionGroupMember $_.Alias  | sort Name | Foreach-Object {
        $_.DisplayName| Add-Content $saveto
    }
}
```

Running this Output the group DisplayName followed by the User DisplayName in a list underneath.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have workaround if not an answer for you - here's a simplified version of your script (minus the formatting):

```
Get-DistributionGroup | select -Property alias | Foreach-Object {
    Get-DistributionMember S_.Alias | Foreach-Object {
        $_.Name | Add-Content $saveto
    }
}
```

See what I did there? Instead of passing on the object from distribution group directly to foreach (which somehow makes it break), I have instead chosen to create a property array and pass that on to the foreach.

This works, I tried it. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful if you want to get membership of single/particular distribution group(s).

```
$ExportCSV=".\DistributionGroupMembersReport.csv"
$DG=Import-Csv -Header "DisplayName" $GroupNamesFile
 foreach($item in $DG)
 {
  Get-DistributionGroup -Identity $item.displayname | Foreach{
    $DisplayName=$_.DisplayName
    $Members=Get-DistributionGroupMember -ResultSize Unlimited -Identity $DisplayName
    $MembersCount=($Members.name).Count
    if($MembersCount -eq 0)
    {$Member="No Members"
     $Result=@{'DisplayName'=$DisplayName;'Members'=$Member
     $Results= New-Object PSObject -Property $Result 
     $Results | Select-Object DisplayName,Members| Export-Csv -Path $ExportCSV - 
       Notype -Append}
    elseif{
     foreach($Member in $Members)
     {
      $Result=@{'DisplayName'=$DisplayName;'Members'=$Member
      $Results= New-Object PSObject -Property $Result 
      $Results | Select-Object DisplayName,Members| Export-Csv -Path $ExportCSV -Notype -Append
   }}}
```

For more detailed report/attributes, you can refer this source script : [Export Office 365 Distribution Group Members to CSV](https://o365reports.com/2019/05/23/export-office-365-distribution-group-members-csv/)

Answer (score 0):

And joining the previous answers to get something that works on my instance, you can try this:

```
Get-DistributionGroup | select -Property PrimarySMTPAddress | ForEach-Object {
    "`r`n$($_.PrimarySMTPAddress)`r`n============="
    Get-DistributionGroupMember $_.PrimarySMTPAddress | ForEach-Object $_.PrimarySMTPAddress
}
```

I'm using the PrimarySMTPAddress instead of Alias because I have multiple lists with the same Alias but different domain names.

Answer (score 0):

```
$groups = (Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited).PrimarySMTPAddress

$Results = foreach ($group in $groups){
  $dist = Get-DistributionGroup $group
  $members = (Get-DistributionGroupMember $group).name
  $dist | Select-Object *,@{n="members";e={$members -join ';'}}
}

$Results | Export-Csv All-DLs-and-Members.csv -NoTypeInformation
```